# WPF DataGrid bound to DataTable not displaying custom objects

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datatable, datagrid

I am trying to display a dynamically created DataTable with a DataGrid. The DataTable can have up to n columns, where column 1 contains strings, which represent company names. Columns 2...n contain objects of a custom type, BalanceOnDate. The header for each of these columns is a string representing a date.

The headers and my first column of strings are displaying properly, but the rest of the columns which are supposed to show the BalanceOnDate objects are empty. I have checked that my DataTable is not empty, so there is some problem where the DataGrid is not displaying the BalanceOnDate objects as strings.

Does anyone know how I can fix this so that the columns of type BalanceOnDate will show the string representation of each object, by calling BalanceOnDate.ToString()? Or perhaps there is some way I can create a converter for the BalanceOnDate objects.

Thanks.

Creating my columns for the DataTable:

```
private void GenerateDates(DateTime firstDate, DateTime lastDate)
{
    DailyLiquidity.Columns.Add("Company");
    int i = 1;
    for (DateTime date = firstDate; date <= lastDate; date = date.AddDays(1), i++)
    {
        DailyLiquidity.Columns.Add(date.ToString(columnNameFormat), typeof(BalanceOnDate));
    }
}
```

Populating the rows:

```
DailyLiquidity.Rows.Add(companyName);
i++;
DailyLiquidity.Rows[i].SetField(dueDate, new BalanceOnDate(companyName, dueDate, new Money(amount), invoiceNumber));
```

Binding the DataGrid to the DataTable:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" ItemsSource="{Binding DailyLiquidity}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" FrozenColumnCount="1" >
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Seems to work fine for me.  I'm using my own custom type of course because there is not enough information in your question to replicate completely your environment.  But is created a DataColumn in a DataType with a custom type and used DataGrid with auto generated columns to display value of custom type.  Not sure what is wrong with your code.

Comment: Thanks. My column names had periods in them and that was causing the binding to fail.